# Using provider DB2OLEDB for a link server to AS400, select a column with character Ñ

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ibm-midrange, sql-server-2014

I have a link server to AS400 I am using DB2OLEDB provider, it works pretty fine, I need to select a column which on It's name has a Character Ñ, Provider throws me this error:

> OLE DB provider "DB2OLEDB" for linked server "AIRS" returned message
>   "Símbolo ^?( + - ? : DAY NOT RRN CASE CAST CHAR DATE DAYS HASH HOUR
>   LEFT no válido. Símbolos válidos: . SQLSTATE: 42601, SQLCODE: -104".
>   Msg 7215, Level 17, State 1, Line 72 Could not execute statement on
>   remote server 'XXX'.

This are my tries:

```
EXEC('SELECT * FROM AICOLDP.FCOB10 WHERE PDAÑOC=2015 FETCH FIRST 10 ROW ONLY') AT AIRS

SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(AIRS, 'SELECT * FROM AICOLDP.FCOB10 WHERE PDAÑOC=2015 Fetch First 100 row only');
```

Comment: You have two types of statements there...do they both throw the same error, different error, or does one of them work?

Comment: It also don't works on SSIS

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to escape the column name with double quotes:

```
SELECT * FROM AICOLDP.FCOB10 WHERE "PDAÑOC"=2015
```

Comment: It didn't work, the provider throws this error:

OLE DB provider "DB2OLEDB" for linked server "AIRS" returned message "La columna *N no está en las tablas especificadas. SQLSTATE: 42703, SQLCODE: -206".
Msg 7321, Level 16, State 2, Line 27
An error occurred while preparing the query "SELECT * FROM AICOLDP.FCOB10 WHERE "PDAÑOC"=2015 Fetch First 100 row only" for execution against OLE DB provider "DB2OLEDB" for linked server "AIRS".